# How do I do "git update"?

Tags: git, github

I set up my git account on Machine A, did a "`git commit`", then "`git push origin master`".

On Machine B, I did a `git clone XXX` ...and it cloned it from my origin.

Now, after I make changes and push it to origin, how do I "update" my Machine B with the latest changes? What if I made changes already on Machine B?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ git pull origin master
```

EDIT:
If you have uncomited changes, you can save then using the stash command before the pull command, and then you apply the stash to the updated changes

```
$ git stash
$ git pull origin master
$ git stash apply
```

Comment: But when I do that, it prompts me about "stashing" or something?

Comment: @Owalla: That's because you have uncommitted changes on machine B. `git status` should give you more details.

Comment: PS: in _most_ cases you can omit the `origin master` portion and just type `git pull`.

Comment: just updated the code for you to save the changes you have made to your code using stash